# Map not loading while changing the map api key in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I had developed an app which shows map to show map obviously we need to generate map api key, which is generated in one specific machine but when i import the same app in some other machine and run the code then map wont be shown due to mismatch of key. still if i want to load the map for that what all changes do i need to make in google map api console to generate new map api key so that I can load map?

Comment: Your mismatch api key is because of your different SHA-1 algo. So obviously you need to create API key using that another machine SHA-1 algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do i need to make in google map api console to generate new map api
>   key so that I can load map

Of course you'll need to generate a new API key because if you change the system, then the SHA-1 certificate is also changed.

Comment: Yes I have generated the sh-1 key after that do I need to create a new project or i can get from already existing project? I found the options Generate new key...
Revert to obsolete key...
Edit allowed Android apps... which option do i need to select?

Comment: @user448250 No need to generate a New Project. You just select already existing project and generate a New key with new SHA-1 that you generate in your new system...

Answer (score 2):

Go to developer console  -> your project -> credential[image]

In credential , click on 'Edit allowed android application' and in that, replace your previous SHA key(Key shown in yellow box) with new key. No need to recreate key and change in manifest file.

For SHA key, go to eclipse preferences as shown in figure[image]

Comment: I did the same, after replacing the new api key in manifest maps are not loading. What might be the issue?

Comment: I think your api key will not be changed, as you are editing existing key so no need to change in manifest. And try to uninstall app once and then try to open it.. It will surely display map. And if still not display then it might b issue of SHA key. If you are directly running app from eclipse then SHA will be of eclipse and if you are generating apk from keystore then SHC will be of your keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Each machine has its own debug certificate.

The standard locations are -

- *Windows Vista: C:\Users\your_user.android\debug.keystore*
- *Windows XP: C:\Documents and
  Settings\your_user.android\debug.keystore*
- *Linux and Mac OS X: ~/.android/debug.keystore*

If you still have a confusion then you can location the keystore by using Eclipse and choosing

```
 Window > Preferences > Android > Build.
```

Then use the following command at a shell prompt that will return the SHA-1 fingerprint of the debug certificate:

```
  keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore> 
-storepass android -keypass android
```

where,

```
<path_to_debug_keystore> = Path to your keystore
```

Then Copy and save the SHA-1 fingerprint.

Now open [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect) to create an API project.
I assume that this part is done by you.

So then request a Maps API key.

For that -

1) Navigate to your project at [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect) .

2) Click API Access in the left navigation bar.

3) This window will display a list of any keys that you have previously created. To create a new key, click Create New Android Key (there are multiple buttons for different kinds of keys; be sure to select the right one).

4) In the window that opens, paste the SHA-1 key from your machine into the input field, followed by a semicolon and the full package name for your app, as illustrated in the following figure.

[image]

**Note:**

If the certificate is different then the matching will get failed.

For that you can share the certificate between the two machines. If you want then you can generate another map api key.

Then when you release the application on Google Play Store, you need to generate a new .keystore that you sign your release builds with - that has to be registered for its own map api key as well.